# Gulp does not minify the images

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, gulp, minify

I need to minify several images but I can not with the gulp.

I already modified the code but found no image.

```
// gulpfile.js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');

gulp.task('minify-img', function () {
   return gulp.src('img/*')
   .pipe(imagemin())
   .pipe(gulp.dest('img/'))
});
```

Minify the images inside in the folder img.

Comment: The gulp.src is relative to your gulpfile.js location.  So is the 'img' directory at the same level as your gulpfile.js?  Otherwise there is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: Yes, same level.

Comment: @DaviLuis - Did you find a solution? I have the same problem. Maybe it is because I am using Ubuntu